# Is there an efficient way to provide an alias for a class member in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is a base class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    int foo;
    // ...
};
```

This class is declared in a header file that I cannot change because I don't have the rights to do so.

Here is a derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // provide alias to Base::foo
    // ...
};
```

Is there a way I can provide an alternate name that refers to Base::foo inside class Derived without using pointers or references?

In other words, is there any way to provide an alias without adding any extra class members to `Derived`?

Also, if conditional compilation directives can be avoided, that would be ideal.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following at all. You want to provide a name that refers to something else... Without using references? And without adding a class member to Derived? That seems completely contradictory to me.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you need to alias?  What is wrong with just using `Base::foo`?  Are you trying to add a public member so someone with a derived class can easily access the foo member from the base?

Comment: Not really a conditional compilation directive, but bad practive nonetheless: `#define bar foo`

Comment: I need to provide a derived class with a different base class than the original class hierarchy.  This alternate class hierarchy is used when a certain compiler preprocessing directive is specified.  So the alternate class hierarchy itself is controlled via conditional compilation directives.  The original hierarchy contained a base class member with a different name than the base in my alternate hierarchy.  And unfortunately a lot of code external to this references the original base class member.  So in order to avoid changing all the surrounding code...

Comment: @AdrianMole Can you do that when `base::foo` is a member variable not a type?

Comment: @AdrianMole That syntax does not work for class members:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration  You are confusing it with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Comment: @NathanPierson No, you can't. I need nicotine, caffeine or (preferably) beer!

Comment: @JDługosz See my other comment. ;(

Comment: we agree that the actual problem is that `Base::foo` is public and that the actual solution would be to do the refactoring, right? Just asking because if you just want to do it "somehow" but don't care about it to be clean, then many things are possible...

Comment: yeah, i guess so.  i just wish there was a way to add aliases to members in an inheritance hierarchy.  but i suppose a feature like that would cause too much confusion through misuse.

Comment: such feature would be against what inheritance is meant to be good for. I was thinking of some workaround, but "without pointers or references" makes this task impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no renaming feature (though there was some work done on such a feature in the early days but it was dropped).

There's no way to do what you want other than adding the desired name as a member to `Derived`, and forwarding it to the base class function.  Note however that this can be inline and should be absorbed by the compiler so it won't hurt performance.